# How to create my own calendar instead of excluding date like holiday calendar in quartz scheduler

Tags: cron, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I want to create my own calendar example: In a month, i can have 33 days and 53 weeks in a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to implement the Quartz [Calendar](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.2/org/quartz/Calendar.html) interface or extends Quartz [BaseCalendar](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.2/org/quartz/impl/calendar/BaseCalendar.html) class and implement/override `getNextIncludedTime` and `isTimeIncluded` methods. Then you simply register the new calendar implementation with Quartz by invoking [scheduler.addCalendar(name, new YourCalendar(), true, true)](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.2/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#addCalendar(java.lang.String,%20org.quartz.Calendar,%20boolean,%20boolean)). From now on you can have your triggers refer to your custom calendar to exclude whatever dates/daytimes you want.

Comment: I already have holiday calendar, mentioned in cron uri like         from("quartz2://groupName/timerName?cron=" + cronexp +"&customCalendar="mycalendar").process(). So, is possible to append two calendars?

Comment: A trigger can only have a single calendar, but you can combine calendars through the "base calendar" functionality. I.e. your custom calendar can use another calendar as its base calendar and this base calendar can use another calendar as its base calendar and so on. Your custom calendar's getNextIncludedTime and isTimeIncluded methods must invoke these methods in the base calendar (chain) and consider the obtained return values when creating its own return values.

Comment: Could you share any reference related to basecalendar?

Comment: If you look at the HolidayCalendar class, you will find out it provides (1) a constructor that accepts a base calendar instance, (2) all standard Quartz calendar implementations provide setBaseCalendar() method. Then look at the HolidayCalendar implementation class and see how it cooperates with the base calendar (see isTimeIncluded and getNextIncludedTime methods).